# Can I change the Amazon PostgreSQL RDS connection limit?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have an Amazon PostgreSQL RDS instance (db.t2.small). I've created a custom parameter group for it and changed the `max_connections` parameter:

[image: max_connections]

However, the "current activity" bar is still showing that the limit is about 200 connections:

[image: current_activity]

Can I change this value somehow or is it a hard limit from Amazon that cannot be changed?

Comment: `max_connections` changes don't take effect until you restart the server, could that be it?

Comment: You probably just need to restart the database instance, but 200 connections for a db.t2.small DB is quite a few.  How come you need so many open connections at once?

Comment: I've restarted the instance and the state of the parameter group is "in-sync".